# How to keep a FrameworkElement at the middle during animation?

Tags: wpf

I try to make a toolBar that is on the Top Center of the Window.

The width of the toolbar may change during the runtime. I want to trigger the width with the help of VisualStates (which seems very practical to me) and Animations (Using Key Frames).

To simplify the issue as much as possible, I put inside a window a DockPanel with inside :

1. a StackPanel containing two buttons (to switch from one visual state to the other one).
2. a Button that will be animated by the two VisualStates added to its ControlTemplate.

Here a screenshot of this window [Screenshot of the Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LvJR.png)

The Xaml Code :

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:is="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="DockPanelIssue.MainWindow"
    Background="LightYellow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
<DockPanel Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Orange" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Margin="5" Click="Show_Click" Content="Show"/>
        <Button Margin="5" Click="Hide_Click" Content="Hide"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="theButton" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ContentControl>
                    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                        <is:ExtendedVisualStateManager />
                    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup is:ExtendedVisualStateManager.UseFluidLayout="True">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:3"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="StateHide">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                        <DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0%" Value="200"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="50%" Value="150"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="100%" Value="100"/>
                                        </DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="StateShow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                        <DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0%" Value="100"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="50%" Value="150"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="100%" Value="200"/>
                                        </DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        Animated Button
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
```

and the code behind to trigger the VisualStates :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Hide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToState(theButton, "StateHide", true);
    }

    private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToState(theButton, "StateShow", true);
    }
}
```

What we were expecting is that the AnimatedButton (the yellow one) increases his width over 3 seconds, ( and stay in the middle ! ). But the result is :

1. Actually , the width is small, we click on the Hide Button.
2. Immediately, the Animated Button is shifted on the Left.
3. the Animated Button is still on the Left, width is growing.
4. Just before the end of the animation, the Animated Button is still on the Left.
5. The Animation is finished, the Animated Button is now taller and it is back on the middle (Phew !)

The beginning and the end is what we want, but the transition ( 2, 3, 4) is not correct.

Here is a picture with the screenshots from step 1 to 5, and drawings that illustrate what we want :

[Screenshots of the Issue and Drawings of what we expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WYFq.png)

How to achieve this ?

Please tell me if I do mistakes.

They are some other points that I don't really understand :

1. Why when i click on hide, the button is growing ( I Expected it shrinking )
2. Why is one of the two animations not playing the transition.
3. Why does the Blue DockPanel takes so much width and so less Height during the Animation (seems that the Orange stackPanel is calculated to be docked at the right during animation instead of Bottom) ?